# Using Facebook Connect to write user's name onto my website

Tags: facebook

Hi I've set up Facebook Connect on my website, and all I want to do is when a facebook user logs in, "welcome 'user name'" will appear. any ideas?

Comment: Ok thanks, so I have to use php?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation of getting user info via facebook connect http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo hope that helps